# Changing compression parameter in python-blosc2

Tags: python, compression, codec, blosc

I wanted to test out [python-blosc2](https://www.blosc.org/python-blosc2/python-blosc2.html).

When trying do compress data with a user-defined Filter however, I stumbled across a for me unexplainable error.

```py
import blosc2  
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

blosc2.compress(a, codec='blosclz', clevel=5, filter=blosc2.Filter.SHUFFLE)
```

I receive a **`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`**

as the documentation said, one should pass the `enum blosc2.Filter` as argument. However, I tried multiple ways, including (but receiving the same error):

```
blosc2.compress(a, codec='blosclz', clevel=5, filter=blosc2.Filter(0))
```

---

I did miss, to uses the enum objects insted of the string for as also pointed out in the [documentation](https://www.blosc.org/python-blosc2/reference/autofiles/top_level/blosc2.compress.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, your code fails [here](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc2/blob/6cd175e491996b85f4b652add3cef8aac7187bc2/blosc2/blosc2_ext.pyx#LL574C14-L574C14). According to the source code of [core.py](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc2/blob/6cd175e491996b85f4b652add3cef8aac7187bc2/blosc2/core.py#L52), `codec` is not supposed to be `str` type. You should pass a value of [blosc2.Codec](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc2/blob/6cd175e491996b85f4b652add3cef8aac7187bc2/blosc2/__init__.py#L18-L31):

```py
blosc2.compress(a, codec=blosc2.Codec.BLOSCLZ, clevel=5, filter=blosc2.Filter.SHUFFLE)
```

Comment: yep, that was it! Thanks! Don't know, why I had the wrong line in the error trace…